# Change IP addresses of a Azure network interface

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-rest-api

I have been asked to change the Azure network interface IP addresses. I understand it can be easily done via portal or Powershell as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-addresses).

However, I would like to the same operation via REST. According to my findings, it is only possible to retrieve the IP configuration of the network interface via REST(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networkinterfaceipconfigurations), but I don't see an endpoint through which I can associate/disassociate the IP addresses from the network interface. Am I overlooking something or it is not supported as of now?

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networkinterfaces/createorupdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Azure network interface IP addresses, one important thing is that a network interface must always have at least one private IPv4 address assigned to it. So the right sequence is:

1. Create a new IP config with the new IP address;
2. Remove the old IP config as you expect.

You can use the REST API: [Network Interfaces - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networkinterfaces/createorupdate) to achieve it, and here is an example, I assume your network interface has only one IP config named `ipconfig1`, then use the REST API with the body below:

```
{
  "name": "nicName",
  "id": "nicResourceId",
  "location": "region",
  "properties": {
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "ipConfigurations": [
        {
            "name": "ipconfig2",
            "properties": {
                "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                "subnet": {
                    "id": "subnetResourceId"
                },
                "primary": true,
                "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
            }
        }
    ],
    "dnsSettings": {
      "dnsServers": [],
      "appliedDnsServers": []
    },
    "enableAcceleratedNetworking": true,
    "enableIPForwarding": false
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
}
```

When it finishes, your network interface will have only one IP config named `ipconfig2` with a new IP address. You can also use the static allocation method and use a special IP address as you want.